# Initializing a float value in Assembly Mips32

Tags: assembly, optimization, mips, mips32

I am learning assembly at my university and I need to do a assembly code that I need to make some float operations, the code is going well so far, but I have a question of optimization. Is there any easiest way to write this:

```
.data
two: .float 2

la $a1, two
l.s $f3, ($a1)
```

I need this constant values to multiply on a bhaskara operation so I initialize that way to use like `mul.s $f4,$f3,$f0`

Comment: Instead of multiplying by two you can add a value to itself.

Comment: Oh, true, it works for this case, but if I need to multiply by four ?

Comment: @Skal Just repeat. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are only two ways of loading a value into a floating-point register on MIPS32: from a general-purpose register (using `mtc1`) or from memory (using `lwc1`/`l.s`).

```
# mtc1 example:
li   $v0, 0x3F800000 # v0 = 1.0f
mtc1 $v0, $f0        # f0 = 1.0f
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of usage please ?

Comment: @Skal Added. Find and use a MIPS instruction reference.

Comment: Thanks. I am using one but it still a little fuzzy for me, it doesn't give much exemples of usage.

Comment: @Skal Find "See MIPS Run Linux", see if it helps.